Как сделать так чтобы при нажатии Enter пользователь возвращался в меню обратно
Работаю с программированием программ на Termux и столкнулся с проблемой что при вводе команды и открытия программы после любого действия программа слетает и ее надо запускать ещё раз
print('''╔══╗─╔══╗╔══╗╔══╗
║╔╗╚╗║╔╗║╚═╗║║╔═╝
║║╚╗║║║║║──║╚╝║──
║║─║║║║║║──║╔╗║──
║╚═╝║║╚╝║╔═╝║║╚═╗
╚═══╝╚══╝╚══╝╚══╝
████─████─████─███─────█
█──█─█──█─█────█──────██
████─████─█─██─███─────█
█────█──█─█──█─█───────█
█────█──█─████─███─────█

████─████─████─███────████
█──█─█──█─█────█──────█──█
████─████─█─██─███──────██
█────█──█─█──█─█──────██──
█────█──█─████─███────████

████─████─████─███────███
█──█─█──█─█────█────────█
████─████─█─██─███────███
█────█──█─█──█─█────────█
█────█──█─████─███────███

████─████─████─███────█───
█──█─█──█─█────█──────█──█
████─████─█─██─███────████
█────█──█─█──█─█─────────█
█────█──█─████─███───────█

████─████─████─███────████
█──█─█──█─█────█──────█───
████─████─█─██─███────████
█────█──█─█──█─█─────────█
█────█──█─████─███────████
''')
color_code = {
"red": "\033[31m"
}
select = input(f'{color_code["red"]}[:D]{color_code["red"]} select >{color_code["red"]}. ') 

if select == '1':
      print('''Текст который выбивает при вводе числа один''')

Как мне сделать так чтобы после того как текст ввелся надо было нажать Enter и вернуться в главное меню (там где у меня page 1 page 2 но без текста который написало после ввода единицы)

Key = 'enter'
    if key == enter:
        return


пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Что это за код?.....
